# How to make cells in a MaterialFX MFXTableView editable?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, user-input, materialfx

I want to be able to enter a string inside a table cell of a `MFXTableView` and invoke a callback if enter is pressed.

Previously, I was using JavaFX instead of MaterialFX and it was working.

```
myEditableTableColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()); // makes the cell editable
myEditableTableColumn.setOnCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<MyObject, String>>(){
  public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<MyObject, String> t){
    MyObject myObj = t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow());
    myObj.setMyValue(t.getNewValue());
    logger.debug("do sth. with my changed object.");
  }
});
```

Comment: `MFXTableView` is not a drop-in replacement for `TableView` and has a different API. As far as I can tell, it doesn't have a built-in editable table cell implementation, so you would need to define your own implementation of `MFXTableRowCell` that implemented the editing behavior.